# Can't connect to database when code is moved to a function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to make a function that counts the total of user in the database.

```
$count = "SELECT COUNT(userid) FROM user ";
$run=mysqli_query($con,$count);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($run);
echo $result[0];
```

The code above works fine. However, when I put it inside a function:

```
<?php
include("db.php");

function popo()
{
    $count = "SELECT COUNT(userid) FROM user ";
    $run=mysqli_query($con,$count);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($run);
    echo $result[0];
}
?>

<?php
popo();
?>
```

The following errors appear:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\includes\function.php on line 5
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\includes\function.php on line 6

Comment: Did you checked your database connection ?

Comment: Yep just checked. Weird thing is if I removed the function (), it will work. But if I include it will not work.

Comment: Have check what you get in `$con`, when you can `popo()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$con` doesn't exist inside the function, only outside it.

You could either pass `$con` to the function like this:

```
function popo($con)
...
popo($con);
```

or you could make it global (but this is not great style):

```
function popo() {
  global $con;
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$con` isn't in the scope of function `popo()`. What you could do is use the `global` command:

```
function popo()
{
    global $con;
    // ...
```

Be advised though that using globals like that is a bad practice in programming.

Comment: hmm.. what do you recommend other than global ?

Comment: You could receive it as an argument, like @MattParlane suggested.

Comment: I've also seen some people make a class and have the connection as a static variable on the class.  Then it becomes inherently global